# react-native how to debug on device with wifi/data off?

Tags: react-native

it tries to connect to npm server and throws red screen, I want to test some offline on-load features.

or is there someway to debug without npm server?

Answer (score 3):

To debug offline IOS (react native) you can run two commands: 
- once you turned off your wifi, run this command in the terminal:

`sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 192.xx.xx.xx` - 192.xx.xx.xx is your ip address (you can get the ip address running `ifconfig` command)

After running above command and being offline you should not have the red screen

To undo the above command you run:

`sudo ifconfig lo0 -alias 192.xx.xx.xx`, being still offline you will get now the red screen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, should I turn off my wifi on my computer or on my iphone?
I tried both, but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 1):

To debug on an android device (usb connected) you need to do the following:

1. Enable USB debugging on your android device
2. Navigate to your `AndroidDevelopment/SDKManagerForAndroidStudio/Platform-tools/ directory` in a terminal and type `adb devices` (this should pull up your connected device)
3. Again in the terminal type `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

You should then be able to debug on your device. [Here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html) is a link to the docs (I think they explain how to go about this on ios, I've only tried it on Android)

Comment: eh? then how does my phone connect to my computer? it uses ip address, which means no network = can't connect to debugger

Comment: Didnt catch that it was a real device, in that case i will revise my answer.